# How to return Django Nested Json?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner at Django. I want to create an API JSON Response in below format,
like Every Faculty have some Department and Every Department have some Teacher Information.
Please help me to create this kind of complex JSON format

```
faculty
     Department
          Teacher
```

I have a Teacher model

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11,blank=False,null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
    priority = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
```

serializer.py

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I think your must also break your model into (department, faculty and teacher). If you want I can provide model breakup also along with json

Comment: please give me, this really help me